# Script execution blocked after first execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the dashboard from my project, the follow code handle all clicks in hyperlinks:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#box').draggable();
    $('#box').hide();

    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#box').hide();
        $('a').unbind();
    });

    $('a').click(function(e){
        if($(this).attr('href') != 'logout.html') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
                var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});
                $('#title').text($temp.find('title').text());
                $('#text').html($temp.remove('head').html());
                $('#box').show();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The content of the pages is opened in this `<div>`:

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="header"> <span id="title"></span> <span id="button">X</span> </div>
    <div id="text"> </div>
</div>
```

My problem is: after I "close" the `<div>` by clicking in 'button', I can't access the other options anymore, because all of them stay blocked. When I refresh the page all back to work.

Someone knows how to solve this?

Comment: please make a JSFiddle to show it, I'm tired of making them myself.

Comment: what options are blocked?

Comment: You should show all of your html.  But if I had $5 to bet, I'd bet that all of your `div`'s have `id="box"`.

Comment: Also where is this a href you refer to the code looks like its correct, you click on the button it goes away.  You want it back, did you expect it to come back with magic fairy pixie dust?

Comment: @ChrisRockwell if all div's has id="box" the the id selector will select only the first element with the said id

Comment: no, only the div displayed in the question have id=box. but all the links from the page stay unacessible after I close the div.

Comment: yes because you have `$('a').unbind();` it removes all event handlers from anchor elements

Comment: It does what it suppose to      $('a').unbind(); remove that  RTFM

Comment: but without this line **$('a').unbind()** still don't work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YtjA2/

Comment: Fiddle doesn't work because you haven't loaded jQuery UI, so `draggable` isn't defined, and because the URL you try to access with `$.get` isn't on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DEg52/1/

Comment: seems fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DEg52/3/

Comment: try click in one link, close it, and then click in another. will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after more tryouts I managed to find the problem: happens that the pages I open in the  `<div>` have some included scripts on them. When I remove this scripts, the behaviour in the parent window back to normal. Probably some type of conflict between the two scripts are happening.